# Hidden selector always deciding that an element is visible, even when its not

Tags: javascript, jquery, hidden, false-positive

One of the things I'm working on for an upcoming project is a callout/tooltip system.  In theory, it's  a simple little thing.  You take some markup like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/C3wvh/32/):

```
<script src='jQuery 1.10.1'></script>
<a href='#' id='callout-link'>Click Me</a>

<div id='callout-id' class='callout hidden'>
    This is my tooltip text.
</div>

/* CSS Styling... */
.callout {
     position: absolute;
     z-index: 2;
}

.hidden {
     display: none;
}
```

...and bind it up in JavaScript so that whenever you click some link it toggles visibility.

```
// ...Page Script...
var $link = $('#callout-link'),
    $callout = $('#callout-id');

$(document).ready(function () {
    var callout = new MyCallout($link, $callout);
    callout.bindToControlClick();
});

// ...Object Definition...
var MyCallout = function ($control, $callout) {
    init();

    // Public Scope...
    var pub = {};
    pub.$actionControl = $control;
    pub.$callout = $callout;

    pub.bindToControlClick = function () {
        pub.$actionControl.click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();

            toggleCallout();                
        });
    }

    // Private Scope...
    function init() {
        // The callout-content subdiv is necessary for other operations that are
        // likely not relevant to the problem I am encountering.
        if($callout.children('.callout-content').length == 0)
            $callout.wrapInner('<div class="callout-content" />');
    }

    function toggleCallout() {
        if(pub.$callout.is(':hidden')) {
            // Show is actually more complicated than this, but that's not the problem.
            pub.$callout.show();
        } else {
            pub.$callout.hide();
        }
    }

    return pub;
};
```

The problem is that, while the callout is initially hidden from view, and appears on click, attempting to toggle the callout off fails.  When I add a breakpoint and watch value in the Chrome debugger for `$callout.is(':hidden')`, *even if the element is visible* the watch value evaluates to `true`.

Based on [jQuery's entry for the :hidden selector](http://api.jquery.com/hidden-selector/), it appears that a number of properties are being checked at any given time, which brings me to the **Question:** what is it in my setup that's managing to fool jQuery's `:hidden` selector into always believing the callout to be hidden, even when such is no longer the case?

EDIT: Since I notice a recent question of mine in the side panel, my team has since ensured that our app is running in IE9 Standards mode, so environment should not be a problem this go-round.

EDIT 2: [Fiddle of the problematic code](http://jsfiddle.net/C3wvh/32/) (UPDATED!  Problem reproduced in full.)

Comment: A jsFiddle would be welcome

Comment: Are you testing this in browsers other than IE9?  The IE debugger is OK when you're trying to find IE-only issues, but it's not nearly as usable as Firebug or the Chrome debugger.

Comment: @Pointy: I'm using the Chrome debugger for JavaScript debugging, specifically.

Comment: @Brewal: What is a jsFiddle, exactly?  I haven't heard of this before.

Comment: You realize that `.show()` and `.hide()` won't affect that "hidden" class, right?  I wonder if that has something to do with it.  (I'm not sure how/why that'd affect things ...)

Comment: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) is a great thing to see the behaviour of your js/css/html code

Comment: @Pointy - The `hidden` class has no effect.  I took the `hidden` class off of the callout, and this issue is still occurring for some reason.  I was hoping that was it...I guess it isn't...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was actually a CSS problem - while my code is sane (as the jsFiddle in my OP shows), the `.callout` div was rendering with default dimensions of `width: 0; height: 0`, which causes `:hidden` to select the element.

All I had to do was add the following CSS to solve my problem:

```
.callout {
    width: 1em;
    height: 1em;
    /* ...As before... */
}
```

**Lesson:** Always inspect elements!  What looks like a script error, may in fact be something else entirely.

Answer (score 2):

Try using [hasClass](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/) instead :

```
function toggleCallout() {
    if(pub.$callout.hasClass('hidden')) {
        pub.$callout.removeClass('hidden');
    } else {
        pub.$callout.addClass('hidden');
    }
}
```

Or even quicker with [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleClass/) :

```
function toggleCallout() {
    pub.$callout.toggleClass('hidden');
}
```

Also make sure to put your `MyCallout` declaration before using it, otherwise you will get an error like

> Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

when calling

```
var callout = new MyCallout($link, $callout);
```

The working **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLTk3/1/)**

Comment: While a good suggestion, there are other things at work here - I wasn't *exactly* asking for an alternate implementation, I'm trying to figure out why `:hidden` is being fooled; when I have that critical piece of the puzzle, I can find the fix that's most suitable to the particulars of my team's project on my own.

Comment: Well, I didn't really looking for what caused the problem here because I think you shouldn't use the jquery hidden selector here. It's cleaner to just toggle the class instead of keeping the hidden class even if the element is actually displayed. I will edit my answer with `toggleClass()` jQuery method, that is even more fitted.